# Plot a curve in grafana

Tags: grafana

I have a 2-D time series for which I take 1-minute snapshots that I put in my influxdb.

To give a concrete example, consider a yield curve : this is a curve giving the interest rate by maturity date and looks like this:

```
maturity | 1YEAR | 2 YEARS | 2 YEARS | 3 YEARS | 4 YEARS | 5 YEARS |
interest | 0.5   | 0.75    | 0.83    | 0.99    | 1.01    | 1.05    |
```

My application takes snapshots of the curve and stores them in influxdb.

Now I want to plot these snapshots in grafana. So at one particular time stamp I want to plot the curve (X axis will be my maturities, and Y axis the corresponding interest rates for each maturity).

Can this be done in Grafana?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, this is not currently possible with Grafana. One of your axes must always be time.